# PDT [95116] FATAL: could not access file "pg_stat_monitor": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-14

Recently I accidentally added pg_stat_monitor as a shared preload library but now I can't start my postgres database server because of PDT [95116] FATAL:  could not access file "pg_stat_monitor": No such file or directory. I went to the postgresql.config file but the shared_preload_libraries section is an empty string.

Comment: Are you sure there is only one line setting shared_preload_libraries?  If there is more than one, the last one prevails.  Did you look in postgresql.auto.conf for it too?

Comment: @jjanes yep, was just going to update my post. I found it in postgresql.auto.conf like you said